# How to replace values of a character column based on the occurrence of specific strings in another column of an R data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling with replacing a string at a specific row of my data frame.

In this example, there are mistakes in the `class1` column, so I need to change two species classes.

Here is my code:

```r
class1 <- c("Sarcopterygii", "Actinopterygii", "Actinopterygii", 
            "Actinopterygii", "Actinopterygii", "Actinopterygii", 
            "Actinopterygii", "Insecta", "Insecta")

Species1 <-c("Protopterus aethiopicus","Synodontis ruandae",
             "Synodontis afrofischeri", "Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris", 
             "Schilbe intermedius", "Hoplobatrachus occipitalis",
             "Raiamas salmolucius","Trithemis pluvialis","Trithemis donaldsoni")

count1 <- c(12, 2, 32, 4, 6, 7, 8, 13, 10)

Dataset1 <- data.frame(class1, Species1, count1)
```

I wanted to replace the `"Actinopterygii"` genus with `"Amphibia"` for the species `"Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris"`, and also do the same for the species `"Hoplobatrachus occipitalis"`

Comment: 'I wanted to replace "Actinopterygii" genus for "Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris" with "Amphibia", and also do the same for "Hoplobatrachus occipitalis"'
Not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just trying to change two specific values? If so, I would just use base R subsetting:

```r
## Find the species for which the class needs replacing:
rows_to_fix <- Dataset1[["Species1"]] %in% c("Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris", "Hoplobatrachus occipitalis")

## At those elements, replace Class1 with "amphibia"
Dataset1[["Class1"]][rows_to_fix] <- "amphibia"
```

One advantage of this approach is that it makes it clearer that you're just tweaking a couple of specific errors, rather than generalising for a set of rules

Comment: Thank you so much! I have modified the last syntax! as I want to change string values in the class column.  Dataset1[["class1"]][4,6] <- "amphibia"

Comment: Oh yes, I've mixed up my variables. I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood your goal but here is the main idea with `dplyr::case_when`

```r
library(dplyr)
Dataset1 %>% 
  mutate(class1 = case_when(class1 == "Actinopterygii" ~ "Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris", TRUE ~ class1))
```

Comment: Note that this replaces all instances of `"Actinopterygii"` in `class1` with "`Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris`", which I don't think is what the asker expects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### rename Species1

```r
Dataset1[Dataset1$class1 == "Actinopterygii" & Species1 == "Hyperolius cinnamomeoventris", "Species1"] <- "Amphibia"

Dataset1[Dataset1$class1 == "Actinopterygii" & Species1 == "Hoplobatrachus occipitalis", "Species1"] <- "Amphibia"
```

#### group dataframe

```r
Dataset2 = Dataset1 %>% group_by(class1, Species1) %>% summarise(count1 = sum(count1))
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to recount, because none of the values of `Species1` are duplicated?